# Determining length between vectors giving erroneous results

Tags: c++, vector

This is the beginning of my code that's supposed to be attached to a much larger code where I have to use 3 vectors to determine if I have a triangle, and if so, compute the area with multiple methods(like Heron's formula) for a homework assignment.

My main question is that, given the code below, which should result in sides with lengths of 5/4/3 respectively...  why am I getting results of 4.6e-310/6.9e-310/0.

I am aware that my code may not be pretty, and may have gross conceptual errors, but I've only been learning C++ for 3 weeks after studying Fortran for a month.... and I feel super lost trying to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

// design vector class
class Vector {
    private:
    double Side1() {
        return sqrt(pow(p1x-p2x,2)+pow(p1y-p2y));
    }
    double Side2() {
        return sqrt(pow(p2x-p3x,2)+pow(p2y-p3y,2));
    }
    double Side3() {
        return sqrt(pow(p3x-p1x,2)+pow(p3y-p1y,2));
    }

    public:
        double p1x=1.0, p2x=4.0, p3x=4.0;
        double p1y=5.0, p2y=9.0, p3y=5.0;
};
// get length
int main() {
    double Side1, Side2, Side3;
    std::cout << "Side 1 length is " << Side1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Side 2 length is " << Side2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Side 3 length is " << Side3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything... Other than printing three uninitialized doubles.

Comment: like i mentioned, i just started learning.  so i'm not even sure what you mean by that.  am i not printing the results of the above functions?  cause that's what i'm trying to do.

Comment: You aren't calling those functions.

Comment: ok.  not sure why i'm even getting an answer then, but i guess i know what to look up next now.  thanks

Comment: @DKLlama You created 3 variables in `main`. They are unitialiazed, so they may contain any value, but they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of errors in your code:

First, your functions are `private`. This means you cannot ever call these functions, except from within another function of this class. You probably meant to have public funtions and private data members instead:

```
class Vector {
    public:
    double Side1() {
        return sqrt(pow(p1x-p2x,2)+pow(p1y-p2y));
    }
    double Side2() {
        return sqrt(pow(p2x-p3x,2)+pow(p2y-p3y,2));
    }
    double Side3() {
        return sqrt(pow(p3x-p1x,2)+pow(p3y-p1y,2));
    }

    private:
        double p1x=1.0, p2x=4.0, p3x=4.0;
        double p1y=5.0, p2y=9.0, p3y=5.0;
};
```

Second, you need an object of the type `Vector` (because your functions are not `static` members of this class). Then, on this object, you need to call your methods.

```
int main() {
    Vector v; // create object
    std::cout << "Side 1 length is " << v.Side1() << std::endl; //note the call operator () 
    std::cout << "Side 2 length is " << v.Side2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Side 3 length is " << v.Side3() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your current code creates 3 unitialized `double` variables, which have nothing in common with your functions (they just share the name).

Comment: thank you very much.  i didn't realize i had to do a seperate call.  i thought just by naming them the same it would pull it i guess??  i had another error in my code, but was able to get the desired results with your input.

Comment: just wanted to give you an update, that i was able to get about 90% off the code completed and working with one calculation exception.  most of the confusion comes from the wording of the question(i attend a foreign college).  thanks again for your help, i'm finally starting to understand the programming language a bit.